# This VS example project shows blank forms in the designer, why?

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

The newer [Simple Multi-User TCP/IP Client & Server using TAP](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Simple-Multi-User-TCPIP-1ff0da41) example by the genius Reed Kimble, when opened in VS 2015 Community, shows blank forms for both client and server:

[image: Blank designer form...]

What I mean is, the form designer shows empty forms for both, however the control creation code does exist in the .vb files, leading to a working assembly, without the ability to redesign the form. (In any graphical way, anyhow.)

[image]

Googled this "issue" for more than several hours. Apparently this is fairly common. I found out that it is often due to a broken .vbproj file:

```
<Compile Include="Form1.vb">
  <SubType>Form</SubType> 
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form1.Designer.vb">
  <DependentUpon>Form1.vb</DependentUpon>  '<-- this is often missing!
</Compile>
```

I checked all .vbproj files and these all seem correct. There are no errors at project load or build. Does anyone have a clue what *else* would cause this behavior?

Comment: I checked the Form1 designer code and there are no components created inside it. They are just blank forms. Is this actually an issue or are you just expecting textboxes that never existed? Could you provide screenshots of what you see?

Comment: If the controls are added at runtime then you won't see them in the Visual Studio designer. Your screenshot shows some code where the controls are added. What method is that?

Comment: Exactly what @ChrisF said. You will need to design the form yourself and then remove the code that adds the controls to the form, or make all changes in that code. But I'm voting to close this on the grounds that there is no actual issue.

Comment: The method shown is the Form1_Load of Form1. This was renamed to  ServerForm1 in the illustration, because there were two Form1's and I tried making these names unique in case the designer was getting confused about which form to display. Guess I am barking up the completely wrong tree here. Thanks for the help, I'll delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no components created in the .desginer file then Visual Studio can only ever display a blank form.

It looks like all the controls are created and placed on the form at runtime - via the code in the `FormLoad` event handler. This is why you see the forms in all their glory when the code actually runs.

Both solutions are equally valid approaches, which one works for you will depend on what you want to be able to do. If, as you say, you want to be able to change the design of the form quickly and easily you'll have to remove the code from the `FormLoad` event handler an put the equivalent code in the .designer file. You may be able to do this by simply copying the code, but it will probably be safer to start again from scratch by dragging components onto the form from the toolbox.